# Handcode or not, new e-shop?

Tags: wordpress, e-commerce, virtuemart

As a junior developer, I mean without great experience, what would you do for a client about an eshop? Start from scratch and handcode an e-shop(simple one)? If yes are there any good tutorials you suggest?

Or buy something ready, lets say VirtueMart templates for joomla or a similar solution for Wordpress?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if you described yourself as an expert I still wouldn't recommend that you write an ecommerce application from scratch unless

- your client does something very specific that can't be made to fit an existing solution
- your client has huge amounts of money and doesn't want you to deliver anything for months (or more)
- you can offset either of the above because your business plan is to develop the next Magento and you have the resources to hire a development team and market your solution

Displaying products on the front end is relatively trivial. The rest of the iceberg e.g. security, user management, the back end (admin interface) of your website, tax calculations, shipping, cart functionality, templates, payment gateways etc. would take considerably longer.

Unfortunately, even if you deliver you would still be behind the competition when your client says: "I want feature *x* that I've seen on website *y*" and you have to quote for bespoke development instead of installing or enabling a module on a ready-made application. Unless they're prepared to spend a lot of time and money they will soon look for an alternative.

If you're already using Joomla, I'd recommend installing the Joomla + VirtueMart bundle here:
http://virtuemart.net/downloads

If you're using WordPress take a look at [ShopperPress](http://shopperpress.com/) or [Get Shopped](http://getshopped.org/).

There are many more out there (Magento, osCommerce, Zen etc.)!

The most important thing to do is to match your client's requirements with the features of the application you feel comfortable using.

Answer (score 1):

I would definitely not hand code or encourage this.

It is not sustainable for the client unless him and you are going to work together for the next millennium. What happens is that in a year or two they want new functionality, and **if** you are available, you need to have done a **very very** good job of structuring and commenting your own code to remember it yourself (as a new developer you learn new things every day, and solutions I did a year ago, I would restructure today).

The even more likely scenario is that another developer, system designer or graphic designer comes along, and it will be pointless, enormously time consuming and costly for the client to have person number two dig through your code.

Your time is better spent learning solid cms-systems and improving those, rather than reinventing the wheel. There are too many sites out there that are made as one-offs, and therefore often unmanageable in the long run.

I understand that programmers wants to progam, and the temptation to start with a blank editor page, but it is not good for the client, and it is not good for you reputation down the road.

Use your skills to make unique and custom made plugins, functions etc for your client. Do not waste your time building frameworks that others have already - and most likely - done better.

..and make sure you pick a cms your customer can handle. Do not give him joomla or drupal, if he is of the sort that can barely figure out how to publish a post in wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

You might take this opportunity to learn about recent Web technologies and tools, in particular non-PHP based things like [Opa language](http://opalang.org/) or [Ocsigen library](http://ocsigen.org) or perhaps [Kaya](http://kayalang.org); these tools probably have some useful infrastructure for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You might also checkout [ShopAlternaMart](http://www.alternamart.org/shopalternamart-installation-quick-guide) for WordPress

Answer (score 0):

I'm happy with [opencart](http://www.opencart.com), an open source e-Commerce (see my site [here](http://www.erboristeriasantanna.it), if you like). There are of course many others.

Comment: thank you, it's my first e-commerce, and a live case study also.